# Using homeomorphism to induce an equivalent metric.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, applications, isometry

Suppose $(X,d_1)$ and $(Y,d_2)$ are homeomorphic.Then $\exists f:X\to Y$ homeomorphism.Define $d$ on $X$ by,

$d(x,y)=d_2(f(x),f(y))$ which is a metric on $X$ as $f$ is injective.Now,$f$ is an isometry between $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d_2)$ and hence the topology $\tau_d=\{f^{-1}(U):U\in \tau_2\}$.But $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ have homeomorphism $f$ between them.So,$ \{f^{-1}(U):U\in \tau_2\}=\tau_1$.So,$(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d)$ are equivalent metrics.So,using a homeomorphism between two metric spaces,we can construct an equivalent metric.

Can someone tell me some nice applications of this result?

Comment: The idea is pretty straightforward - doubt there are any nice consequences other than showing that any space homeomorphic to a metric space is metrisable.

Comment: You mean $d(x,y)=d_2(f(x), f(y))$.

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett No,it has,note that $Y$ is a metric space and is isometric to $(X,d)$.So,if $Y$ has some specific properties like totally bounded or complete,then we can induce a metric $d$ on $X$ that also has the same property keeping the topology preserved.In a word,we can guarantee that we can bring in the property without changing the topology of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows e.g. that we can give $\Bbb R$ and equivalent non-complete metric and similarly, we can give $(0,1)$ an equivalent complete metric. It shows how we cannot expect metric notions to be preserved between homeomorphic metric spaces, but that studying isometries and uniform equivalences has some merit in that context. Completeness is "non-topological" in that sense. (Though there *is* a more general notion of topological completeness, which is more appropriate for the purely topological setting).

The "transport of metric" idea also shows that being metrisable is a topological property.